# Laravel serves a phtml file

Tags: 12.04, apache2, php, laravel

I tried running Laravel php framework from my own custom folder (not in '/var/www'). I've set up vhost, and permissions and it seems to work correctly, but Instead of seeing the laravel welcome page, it offers my to download a phtml file.
This post seems tobe relevant:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1519645#post_9539904

But I don't have the /etc/apache2/mods-available/php5.conf file.
Am I on the right track here? How can I fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I was missing the `libapache2-mod-php5` package...